# NODE Js: Wrong file type generating?

Tags: node.js, google-translate, google-text-to-speech

I want to create mp3 file with words I have given it programmatically. I am using Google Text-To-Speech API to convert into .mp3. Code working fine and its also generating file test.mp3 but not in the original format of .mp3 (It is looks like a .mp3 file and cannot open). Can anyone help me on the same.
My code is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var text = 'Hello World';
var options = {
    url: 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&tl=en&client=t',
    headers: {
        'Referer': 'http://translate.google.com/',
        'User-Agent': 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)'
    }
}

request(options)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.mp3'))
```

[image]

Comment: Requesting that particular URL, with those particular headers, yields a 403 ("Forbidden"). It also doesn't look like you're using an official API.

Comment: Thanks@ robertklep : Can you please suggest me the correct one ?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't an official TTS API for Google.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer-

just change the `url` , use simply `+text+`  not `+encodeURIComponent(text)+`

```
url: 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&tl=en&client=t'
```

I dont know why `encodeURIComponent()` is not working. Luckly fixed right now.